# Do all app services on an app service plan share the same cost?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

If I set an app service plan to an S2 and there are 2 (or more) app services on it is the cost 146/month or 146/month * 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can host up to 100 apps in a single app service plan, but the key thing to know here is that as with the free plan you are charged per app, not per app service plan.

When you pick the shared plan it is [charged per instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) in the app service plan.

[image]

Comment: So to confirm, in this case it would be 146 * 2 because i have 2 app services (instances?)

Comment: No. `Pricing is based on the size and number of instances you run` https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

Comment: Instance = VM (scale out on app service), i.e. how many servers are running your apps

Comment: you can estimate here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Why would you be charged for a free plan?

Answer (score 6):

You pay per instance in the App Service plan, the amount of apps you run there does not affect that cost.
You do have to pay some pennies for network traffic going out of your apps, that's per app.

*With the exception of the Shared tier though where you pay per app*.

So the main thing affecting the price is the Scale Up and Scale Out settings on the App Service plan (size of VMs + amount of VMs).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

Shared tier mentions for me:

> ~€8.003/month
>   per site

Basic and Standard tiers mention:

> Pricing is based on the size and number of instances you run.